# Question about a geometric construction

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

Give two points $A$ and $B$ that both lie on the same side of a line $l$, using a compass and straightedge find a point $C$ on $l$ such that $AC$ and $BC$ make the same angle with $l$.

My original idea was to draw the given line $l$ and draw the points A and B on one side of $l$. Then draw a line from A to B, find the bisector of the line AB and wherever the bisector intersects with line $l$ would give me point C. Looking back, I don't think that this is the solution and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Reflect point $B$ in the line $l$.